# ruby's mongo driver: `delete': can't convert Symbol into String (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I got this error:

```
$ ruby mapreduce.rb
/usr/share/gems/gems/mongo-1.6.4/lib/mongo/collection.rb:618:in `delete': can't convert Symbol into String (TypeError)
    from /usr/share/gems/gems/mongo-1.6.4/lib/mongo/collection.rb:618:in `map_reduce'
    from mapreduce.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

with the following code:

```
require 'rubygems' 
  require 'mongo' 

  map = "function() { " + 
  "var keys = [];" + 
  "for ( item in this['kg'] ) { keys.push(item) }" + 
  "emit(keys.sort().join(';'), {count: 1})" + 
  "}" 
  reduce = "function(key, values) { " + 
  "var sum = 0; " + 
  "values.forEach(function(doc) { " + 
  " sum += doc.count; " + 
  "}); " + 
  "return {count: sum}; " + 
  "};" 
  out = "stats" 

  db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("test") 
  coll = db.collection("snps") 

  result = coll.map_reduce(map, reduce, out) 
  result.find.to_a.each do |r| 
puts ['{', r['_id'], ':', r['value']['count'].to_i, '}'].join(" ") 
  end
```

with the following MongoDB 2.2.3.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From the [fine manual](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mongo/Mongo/Collection:map_reduce):

> **- (Collection, Hash) map_reduce(map, reduce, opts = {})**

Note that the third argument to `map_reduce` is supposed to be an options Hash but you're passing a String. If you look inside the `map_reduce` source you'll see this:

```
def map_reduce(map, reduce, opts={})
  #...
  raw    = opts.delete(:raw)
```

so it will end up calling [`String#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-delete) with a Symbol argument instead of the String that `String#delete` is expecting and there's your error.

You'll also find this in the documentation for the options:

> `:out` (`String`) — default: `nil` — a valid output type. In versions of MongoDB prior to v1.7.6, this option takes the name of a collection for the output results. In versions 1.7.6 and later, this option specifies the output type. See the core docs for available output types.

So presumably you want to say:

```
result = coll.map_reduce(map, reduce, :out => out)
```

---

And don't do this:

```
map = "function() { " + 
  "var keys = [];" + 
  "for ( item in this['kg'] ) { keys.push(item) }" + 
  "emit(keys.sort().join(';'), {count: 1})" + 
  "}"
```

Use the `%Q{...}` or `%q{...}` quotes instead:

```
map = %q{function() {
  var keys = [];
  for ( item in this['kg'] ) { keys.push(item) }
  emit(keys.sort().join(';'), {count: 1})
}}
```

That's a lot easier to read and is less noisy and error prone when you have nested quotes.